# Can I flush 1 toilet while the other one is being fixed?

Tags: plumbing

I had to remove the full toilet in our downstairs bathroom to replace the wax ring and flange. Unfortunately I had something come up and was unable to finish the job tonight.

I did put some shop towels in the hole so nothing fell down the pipe until I can finish the job after work tomorrow.

But in the mean time, are we able to use the upstairs bathroom and flush the toilet without it causing any issue with the downstairs one?

The house is almost 100 years old so plumbing might be wacky.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are having other problems (e.g., sewage blockage), this should not cause a problem at all.